# Excel 2010 - Storing Ribbon Customization in Workbook

Tags: excel, ribbon, excel-2010, vba

I'm new to Excel ribbon customization. What is the most straight forward way to store ribbon customization inside a workbook, so that when the workbook is closed the customization disappears without a trace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change the ribbon with a workbook, you need to change the XML file "inside" the xlsx file (which is nothing more but a .zip).

Everything is very well explained here: http://www.rondebruin.nl/ribbon.htm

Please let us know if that does not answer your question.

Comment: That's pretty good explanation. I also found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(office.12).aspx) page.

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way is to right-click on the ribbon & choose customise ribbon, then look on the lower right of the box that opens, choose reset and then confirm.

PS
You can also create *CustomUI Ribbons* in excel by recycling your old excel toolbars!

I must have read 500 pages on customisation and never seen the below gold anywhere.
This method also lets you add a customUI Ribbon NOT LINKED TO or embedded in a workbook.
:-)

**Undocumented feature follows:**
Just open an old *excel12.xlb* from Excel 2007 in Excel Pro 2010 and a shiny new ribbon tab will appear. I have also previously created these in excel 2007 from an old 2003 Excel(X?).xlb which I have been using all the way from Excel5 if memory serves correctly.

It was **not linked to an xls**, so it was viewable even if no sheets were open. (Not just hidden, but actually none open or viewable in VBIDE.) Nothing in the add-ins list either.

I exported this customisation using Excel's utility.
The beauty of this is it makes it very easy to edit the macro paths etc, as I was able to edit the names by opening the *Excel Customizations.exportedUI* in Notepad.
Imported back into Excel using the utility.

The code inside can be used as part of a standard customisation using rels etc. So if you want to add it to a workbook go right ahead, only I put a lot of general utilities in mine.

Here are some snips of my screen to back it up:
(click for full image)

[image]

[image]