# Keep buttons in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I started to learn VBA 2 weeks ago. I have a question regarding the buttons I created to run different procedures.

For instance I created a button (in custom ribbon->assign macro) to run this procedure:

```
Sub MergecsvFiles()
    Shell Environ$("COMSPEC") & " /c Copy C:\Users\user\Desktop\new\*.csv C:\Users\user\Desktop\new\CombinedFile.csv "
End Sub
```

But when I send the macro (xlsm) file via e-mail the buttons are not there. How can I manage to send the macro via e-mail and also keep the buttons?

PS I'm using office 2016.

Comment: Not sure how a button will disappear... What is your excel versions?

Comment: Be clear about how you use the terms. Otherwise no one is able to understand your question. (1) you cannot run a module but a procedure (sub) or a function only. (2) If you send a macro via email this means you send its code only? A macro cannot contain a button, but an Excel file can contain a button and a macro. (3) You see it is very important to use the correct terms if you expect a good answer. Please [edit] your question and make clear what Excel you use and which format the file has (XLSX, XLSM, CSV, etc) **eg. CSV cannot contain buttons or macros**. Also a screenshot could help.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I edited my question

Comment: custom ribbon buttons are not saved in the xlsm files. These are saved on your computer only. Nevertheless you can include ribbons into your Excel file but this is a bit tricky, cumbersome and for advanced users and developers (2 weeks of VBA will not be enough for this task I think). But if you are interested have a look at [Excel 2010 - Storing Ribbon Customization in Workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724923/excel-2010-storing-ribbon-customization-in-workbook) (It's almost the same for Excel 2016).